# The integral of $\exp(-|x-a|)$ over an even dimensional sphere

Tags: reference-request, integration

I'm after a reference for an integral.  For $m$ a positive integer and $R>0$ let $S^{2m}_R\subset \mathbb{R}^{2m+1}$ denote the radius $R$ sphere of dimension $2m$.  Suppose that $a$ lies inside the sphere, i.e. $|a|<R$.  I wish to know the following integral as a function of $R$ and $|a|$.
$$\int_{S^{2m}_R} e^{-|x-a|} \ \ \mathrm{d}x$$
I have a formula essentially in terms of $e^R$, $e^{|a|}$ and [reverse Bessel polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_polynomials) in $R$ and in $|a|$. Sage can verify my formula up to $m=20$ (and beyond).

I haven't yet figured out how to prove the formula, but think that this must be a classical computation.  Can anyone provide me with a reference to this in the literature?

[Edit: I have now asked a new question [Proof of an Identity Involving an Integral over an Even Sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249456/proof-of-an-identity-involving-an-integral-over-an-even-sphere?noredirect=1&lq=1) giving the formula explicitly and asking for a proof. ]

Comment: isn't the calculation just a matter of writing $dx$ in hyperspherical coordinates and carrying out one radial integration and one angular integration?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker  Yes.  That's what how you can calculate the integral and that's how I get Sage to calculate the integral.  However, what I want is a closed form expression in terms of the reverse Bessel polynomials.  As I say what I'm after here is whether or not such a formula has appeared in the literature before.